# Is $^\mathbb{N} \mathbb{R}$ equinumerous to $^\mathbb{R}\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help  answering the question:

Is $^\mathbb{N} \mathbb{R}$ equinumerous to $^\mathbb{R}\mathbb{N}$?

Where: $^\mathbb{N} \mathbb{R}$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $^\mathbb{R}\mathbb{N}$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: What is $^\Bbb N\Bbb R$?

Comment: As a first step to improve your past, please define what you mean by $^\mathbb{X}Y.$  I speak in generality using $X$, $Y$, so you explain, in general what you mean.

Comment: Um, define what each of those mean, please.

Comment: I think the question is asking whether the cardinalities $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph_0^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ are the same. They aren't.

Comment: $^\mathbb{N} \mathbb{R}$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $^\mathbb{R}\mathbb{N}$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @amWhy Though I'm very much interested in how I could improve my past, I have to assume you meant "post"

Comment: @gflkdu769 Normally those are written as $\Bbb{R^N}$ and $\Bbb{N^R}$ respectively.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger  Oh, my! Didn't notice the typo! Seems I made myself the target of a great joke!  :-P

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger, I've seen notation $^YX$ occasionally in courses that first introduce cardinalities to help students not to confuse it with set $\{f\colon X\to Y\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start...

Comment: @gflkdu769, are you familiar with cardinal arithmetic?

Comment: @Ennar no I am not

Answer (score 2):

Here's is one way to show they have different cardinalities using elementary arguments:

$$
\left|^\mathbb{N} \mathbb{R}\right| = |\{f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R\}| = |\{f: \mathbb N \to \{g: \mathbb N \to \{0, 1\}\}\}| = |\{f: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \{0, 1\}\}| = |\{f: \mathbb N \to \{0, 1\}\}| = |\mathbb R|.
$$
Explain why each equality holds above. Here are the steps:

1. Explain why $|\mathbb R| = |\{g: \mathbb N \to \{0, 1\}\}|$ using binary expansions.
2. The third equality is because sequence of sequences is "an infinite matrix".
3. The fourth equality is since $|\mathbb N \times \mathbb N| = |\mathbb N|$ by Cantor's diagonal argument.

On the other hand, $|P(\mathbb R)| = |\{f: \mathbb R \to \{0, 1\}\}| \leq \left|^\mathbb R \mathbb N\right|$. This is because $\{f: \mathbb R \to \{0, 1\}\} \subset \{f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb N\} = {}^\mathbb R \mathbb N$. Now use the well known fact that cardinality of a power set is strictly bigger than the cardinality of the original set so that
$$
\left|^\mathbb{N} \mathbb{R}\right| = |\mathbb R| < |P(\mathbb R)| \leq \left|^\mathbb R \mathbb N\right|.
$$

Comment: No offense, but this must be the ugliest obfuscation of cardinal arithmetic I've ever seen.

Comment: Well OP said they don't know cardinal arithmetic. So I tried to make the math as basic as possible where you only need to know how to construct bijections.

Comment: I know they did, but with bit more effort you could have achieved the same, but readable.

Comment: I see. Please suggest modifications to make it better.

Comment: I've already started to type my own answer before you posted yours, which is similar, but has more details.

Comment: Ok. I only gave a sketch/outline and omitted my details precisely not to do OP's homework and let them fill in the details themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact background of OP but a word or two on the second equality in above answer wouldn't hurt (even just by linking to other answers on Math.SE).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to apply [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) directly, so in part I will essentially redo some of the rules for [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic).

First of all, let us show that $|^\Bbb N\Bbb R|=|\Bbb R|$. This is where, essentially, we are doing cardinal arithmetic.

Let $f\colon 2^\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ and $g\colon\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ be bijections. Hopefully you can prove yourself that these exist.

I claim that $|(2^\Bbb N)^\Bbb N| = |2^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}|$. Indeed, define $$h\colon (2^\Bbb N)^\Bbb N\to 2^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N},\quad h(s)(m,n) = s(m)(n)$$
$$h'\colon 2^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}\to (2^\Bbb N)^\Bbb N,\quad h'(s)(m)(n) = s(m,n)$$ and check that these are inverse to each other.

We can compose bijections to get $$\Bbb R\simeq 2^\Bbb N \simeq 2^{\Bbb N\times \Bbb N}\simeq (2^\Bbb N)^\Bbb N\simeq \Bbb R^\Bbb N$$

where the second bijection is $g'((a_k)_k)(m,n):= a_{g(m,n)}$ and the last bijection is $f'((a_n)_n)=(f(a_n))_n.$

Now, we want to show that $|\Bbb R| < |^\Bbb R\Bbb N|$. This is where we use diagonal argument. Let $\varphi\colon \Bbb R\to{} ^\Bbb R\Bbb N$ be any function and define $$f_{\varphi}\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb N,\quad f_{\varphi}(x) = \varphi(x)(x)+1.$$

We claim that $f_\varphi$ is not in the range of $\varphi$ and thus $\varphi$ cannot be surjective. Assume contrary, that $\varphi(x) = f_\varphi$ for some $x\in\Bbb R$. Then,

$$\varphi(x)(x) = f_\varphi(x) = \varphi(x)(x)+1.$$

Contradiction.

Since, there is no surjection from $\Bbb R$ to $^\Bbb R\Bbb N$, they are not equinumerous. On the other hand, there is clearly an injection $\Bbb R\to{}^\Bbb R\Bbb N$.

Finally, we conclude that $$|^\Bbb N\Bbb R|=|\Bbb R| < |^\Bbb R\Bbb N|.$$

Answer (score 0):

$|\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}|=$ $(2^{\omega})^{\omega}=$ $2^{|\omega \times \omega|}=$  $2^{\omega}=c.$

$|\mathbb N^{\mathbb R}|=$ $ \omega^{|\mathbb R|}$ $\geq 2^{|\mathbb R|}=$ $2^c>c.$

Another way to show that $|\mathbb N^{\mathbb R}|>c$ is to consider $T=\{f_S:S\subset \mathbb R\}$  where $f(x)=1+\chi_S(x)$ where $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function of $S$ (as a subset of $\mathbb R$).

We have $T\subset \mathbb N^{\mathbb R}$ and $|T|=|2^{\mathbb R}|=2^c>c.$